# How to fix SQL error SAP HANA while using aggregate function

Tags: sql, hana

If I run this sql in SAP HANA, It generates the following error.

> (SQL Editor) Could not execute 'WITH l1 AS( SELECT REMOTE_SOURCE_NAME,OWNER,NAME,MAX(START_TIME) START_TIME,RESULT_STATE FROM ...'
> Error: (dberror) 266 - inconsistent datatype: only numeric type is available for SUM/AVG/STDDEV/VAR function: line 43 col 7 (at pos 654)

If I exclude this part of sql `select sum(LOADING_TIME)  AS TOTAL_LOADING_TIME`, then it works.

How can I solve the issue to get `total_loading_time`?

```
WITH l1 AS(
SELECT  REMOTE_SOURCE_NAME,OWNER,NAME,MAX(START_TIME) START_TIME,RESULT_STATE
FROM "MEAG_EIM_SHARED"."meag.eim.shared::replication.Log"
WHERE TYPE = 'INITIAL' AND RESULT_STATE = 'COMPLETED' 
AND REMOTE_SOURCE_NAME='RS_SDI_IMMO'
group by REMOTE_SOURCE_NAME,OWNER,NAME,RESULT_STATE
order by NAME ASC),
l2 AS
(SELECT  REMOTE_SOURCE_NAME,OWNER,NAME,START_TIME,END_TIME,RESULT_STATE
FROM "MEAG_EIM_SHARED"."meag.eim.shared::replication.Log"
WHERE TYPE = 'INITIAL' AND RESULT_STATE = 'COMPLETED' 
AND REMOTE_SOURCE_NAME='RS_SDI_IMMO'
group by REMOTE_SOURCE_NAME,OWNER,NAME,RESULT_STATE,START_TIME,END_TIME
order by NAME ASC)

select sum(LOADING_TIME)  AS TOTAL_LOADING_TIME
from(
select layer1.REMOTE_SOURCE_NAME,layer1.OWNER,layer1.name,layer1.RESULT_STATE,layer1.start_time start_time,layer2.end_time end_time, 
SECONDS_BETWEEN(layer1.START_TIME,layer2.END_TIME) || 's' LOADING_TIME

from l1  layer1 inner join l2 AS layer2
on layer1.start_time=layer2.start_time
order by name);
```

Answer (score 1):

`LOADING_TIME` has the character „s“ concatenated to it - that turns the numeric value into a string.
And for strings there is no `SUM()` function.

If having the „s“ is important then adding it after the summation will fix the issue.
Otherwise, adding the unit denomination (I guess the s stands for seconds) to the column name would allow client tools to still work with the numeric value (I.e. when sorting)